# undefined reference to `dgesv_' when compiling

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc

ROOTPATH = /home/swagatam
LIB_PATH = $(ROOTPATH)/mylib/libf2c.a \
            $(ROOTPATH)/mylib/blas_LINUX.a \
        $(ROOTPATH)/mylib/lapack_LINUX.a -lm


INC_PATH = -I$(ROOTPATH)/myinclude

swadgesv : swadgesv.o
    $(CC) $(LIB_PATH) swadgesv.o -o swadgesv

swadgesv.o : swadgesv.c
    $(CC) $(INC_PATH) -c swadgesv.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

swadgesv.c is program solving equations of the form A.X = B. I need 3 header files and 3 libraries to link to solve the prob. But while I run the Makefile in terminal it shows:

```
gcc -I/home/swagatam/myinclude -c swadgesv.c
gcc /home/swagatam/mylib/libf2c.a /home/swagatam/mylib/blas_LINUX.a         /home/swagatam/mylib/lapack_LINUX.a -lm swadgesv.o -o swadgesv
swadgesv.o: In function `main':
swadgesv.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/home/swagatam/mylib/libf2c.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined  here
/home/swagatam/mylib/libf2c.a(main.o): In function `main':
(.text.startup+0xad): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
swadgesv.o: In function `main':
swadgesv.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `dgesv_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [swadgesv] Error 1
```

And even when I change the order of libraries in LIB_PATH it shows different errors. I am calling a function dgsev from the clapack library I installed.

Answer (score 7):

Put your libraries after your object files:

```
swadgesv: swadgesv.o
    $(CC) swadgesv.o -o swadgesv $(LIB_PATH)
```

If you list the libraries first, the loader is looking for a symbol `main()`, and it usually won't find it in a library, so it has no reason to link any symbols from the libraries and effectively ignores them.  When it finally comes across your object file, it finds `main()`, but doesn't find the symbols referenced by `main()` in the (non-existent) arguments after the object file.  Hence the symbols remain undefined.  The order of the arguments on the link line does matter.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler : Thank You very much. I am really grateful. It worked at last. I didn't know that the ordering will be so important.